# Item succeed after rollback but reported as skipped in Processor

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Processor where a block of code like this is executed:

```
if (!file.exists()) {
            logger.warn("Unknown file " + item.getId());
            SkipReport report = new SkipReport(item.getId(), "Document Skipped");

            List<SkipReport> reports = new ArrayList<SkipReport>();
            reports.add(report);
            try {
                //reporting error in csv file
                reportWriter.write(reports);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            throw new MyException();
}
```

Those type of files are stored in `nfs` so on very rare occasions(As far as I understand) failed to be read but usually after rollback they succeed. The problem is that the first time an item throws this exception, an error is reported(`reportWriter.write()`) which is invalid.

Is there a way to correctly report this issue? (maybe write the report in a listener after rollback).

Comment: Why are you not using the skip capabilities within Spring Batch?  We handle skips for you.  I'd expect you to report via a `SkipListener`.

Comment: Good point! I handle the reporting in processing because I report warnings and other things too. So I imagine using a `SkipListener` and in `onSkipInProcess()` I can check if the exception matches `MyException` and report the issue there?

Comment: You got it!  If you only want to report that type of exception, you wouldn't even need to do the exception check (since you configure what exceptions get skipped).